# Can't generate the valid .json file

Tags: python, json

I have the following python code, in order to generate a json code
It is reading the data from a csv file and the output will be written into a json file through dumps().

```
import os
import csv
import json

csvFilePath = "./mycsv.txt"
jsonFilePath = "./mydata.jsonc"

if os.path.exists(jsonFilePath):
    os.remove(jsonFilePath);

# Dictionary 1
myData1 = {
    "persons" : [
      {"Id": int,
      "groupId": str
      }
    ]
}

# Dictionary 2
myData2 = { 
    "data": [
      { "Id": int,
      "x": float,
      "y": float,
      "z": float
      }
    ]
}

# Init
myVarformyData1 = {}
myVarformyData2 = {}
myVarformyData1["persons"]={}
myVarformyData2["data"]={}

# Process first the sensor data (the first part persons)
with open(csvFilePath, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csvFile:  
    line = csv.reader(csvFile)
    next(line)
    for line in csvFile:
        col = 0
        for value in line.split(';'):
            col = col + 1
            if (col == 3):
                myVarformyData1["persons"]["sId"] = value              
            elif (col == 8):
                myVarformyData1["persons"]["groupId"] = value
        
        with open(jsonFilePath, 'a', encoding = 'utf-8') as jsonFile1:
            jsonFile1.write(json.dumps(myVarformyData1, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
            jsonFile1.close();

# Closing the csv file
csvFile.close();

# Process other data (the second part data)
# Continues reading from the same .csv file 
with open(csvFilePath, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csvFile:  
    line = csv.reader(csvFile)
    next(line)
    for line in csvFile:
        col = 0
        for value in line.split(';'):
            col = col + 1
            if (col == 3):
                myVarformyData2["data"]["sId"] = value
            elif (col == 10):
                myVarformyData2["data"]["x"] = value
            elif (col == 11):
                myVarformyData2["data"]["y"] = value
            elif (col == 12):
                myVarformyData2["data"]["z"] = value

        with open(jsonFilePath, 'a', encoding = 'utf-8') as jsonFile1:
            jsonFile1.write(json.dumps(myVarformyData2, indent=4,sort_keys=True))
            jsonFile1.close();

# Closing the .csv file
csvFile.close();
```

But my code above delivers the following .json file, which is not really correct:

```
{
    "persons": {
        "groupId": "1",
        "sId": "123"
    }
}{
    "persons": {
        "groupId": "2",
        "sId": "456"
    }
}{
    "persons": {
        "groupId": "3",
        "sId": "789"
    }
}{
    "data": {
        "sId": "123",
        "x": "6.11",
        "y": "2.188",
        "z": "1.6"
    }
}{
    "data": {
        "sId": "456",
        "x": "7",
        "y": "2.384",
        "z": "1.6"
    }
}{
    "data": {
        "sId": "789",
        "x": "8.74",
        "y": "1.159",
        "z": "1.6"
    }
}
```

What should I change in my data structure (dictionaries), in order to get the following output as a valid .json file:

```
{
    "persons": [
        {
        "groupId": "1",
        "sId": "123"
    },{
        "groupId": "2",
        "sId": "456"
    },{
        "groupId": "3",
        "sId": "789"
    }
], "data": [ 
    {
        "sId": "123",
        "x": "6.11",
        "y": "2.188",
        "z": "1.3"
    },{
        "sId": "456",
        "x": "7",
        "y": "2.384",
        "z": "1.4"
    },{
        "sId": "789",
        "x": "8.74",
        "y": "1.159",
        "z": "1.5"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You are overengineering this. **Don't write the JSON in a loop.** Build the `dict`/`list` structure into a single variable, then write the entire thing in one shot: `json.dump(jsonFilePath, myVarformyData)`. This way `json` will maintain compliance with the JSON spec and all you need to worry about are Python datatypes.

Comment: I made two typos in my comment above - (1) [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) takes the object to be written first, then (2) a writable file handle second - a la `json.dump(myVarformyData, jsonFile1)` - however the core premise still stands that there is zero reason for you to roll your own JSON writing logic when this exists.

Comment: while declare a csv reader then not use it?

Comment: @esqew: Thanks very much, I will look at it again, but the body of my json file must consists of two pieces, namely 'persons' and 'data' like above. I think, in any case I should therefore work still with these two dictionaries (persons and data).

Comment: @Botticelli I see that, so why not just create a single `dict` with those keys, then fill those keys with their associated `list` objects, then `json.dump` out to a file...? I'm not quite sure what it is about your requirements you feel aren't compatible with this type of design that you have to go out and add all this additional overhead with loops and file writing mechanisms to achieve your desired result. Do you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: @esqew or do you think, I can reach that also with only one single dictionary? Thanx.

Comment: @Botticelli I do - like I said, I personally am not quite sure what's stopping you from doing so.

Comment: Your code isn't working correctly because it repeatedly updates a JSON file instead of converting the data structure and writing all at once as others pointed out. That said, I want to say there isn't enough data provided, what is the structure of the csv file. If you give an example csv file, I can write code to give the intended JSON file.

Comment: @Ξένη Γήινος: It is a semicolon separated file, which consists of many columns and many rows. And I must read first the data about persons and (other) data always from a single row and divide it two pieces (person and data).

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

I did some changes to your code:

- Merged the two for loops since they both iterate over the same .csv file.
- Removed the `jsonFile1.close()`, using `with open(...` eliminates the need to manually close the file.
- Refactored the code to use a single dictionary to store the data. This dict has the two original keys ('persons' and 'data'), each storing a list of dictionaries.
- Removed the need to iterate through all values of the line and used the index to access the values.

```py
import os
import csv
import json

csvFilePath = "./mycsv.csv"
jsonFilePath = "./mydata.json"

if os.path.exists(jsonFilePath):
    os.remove(jsonFilePath)

output_dict = {"persons": [], "data": []}

with open(csvFilePath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as csvFile:
    for line in csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=";"):
        output_dict["persons"].append({"sId": line[3], "groupId": line[8]})
        output_dict["data"].append(
            {"sId": line[3], "x": line[10], "y": line[11], "z": line[12]}
        )

with open(jsonFilePath, "a", encoding="utf-8") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(output_dict, jsonFile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

### Original answer:

You are initializing `myVarformyData1["persons"]` value as a dict. To achieve the result you expected you need to use a list and append the data from each line to it as a dict:

```py
myVarformyData1 = {}
myVarformyData1["persons"] = [] # initialize persons field as a list

with open(csvFilePath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as csvFile:
    line = csv.reader(csvFile)
    next(line)
    for line in csvFile:
        person = {"sId": "", "groupId": ""} # initialize the dict for a single person
        col = 0
        for value in line.split(";"):
            col = col + 1
            if col == 3:
                person ["sId"] = value
            elif col == 8:
                person ["groupId"] = value

        myVarformyData1["persons"].append(person) # append person to the list

# this has to be outside the for loop, writing to the file a single time
with open(jsonFilePath, "a", encoding="utf-8") as jsonFile1:
    jsonFile1.write(
        json.dumps(myVarformyData1, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    )
    jsonFile1.close()
```

With this you solve the problem for the `persons` key. You can fix the rest of you code for the `data` key on a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simplify your code quite a bit. The key points here are using the `CSV` package to read your data and then assemble rows of output in lists that you can dump. I don't have test data to work with, but I think this might do the trick.

```py
import csv
import json

csvFilePath = "./mycsv.txt"
jsonFilePath = "./mydata.jsonc"

persons, data = [], []
with open(csvFilePath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as csvFile:  
    for row in csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=";"):
        persons.append({"sId": row[3], "groupId": row[8]})
        data.append({"sId": row[3], "x": row[10], "y": row[11], "z": row[12]})
results = {"persons": persons, "data": data}

with open(jsonFilePath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as jsonFile1:
    json.dump(results, jsonFile1, indent=4)
```